# How can I delete a gameobject that is part of prefab without damage the prefab?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this door standing in the air and I don't it.
When I try to delete the door I'm getting the message:

[image: Door prefab]

The door is part of the prefab name: Circular_Room_01

When I click on Open Prefab I see:

[image: Door prefab]

Not seems to be the same door as before. Not same position.
All I want is to delete the door in the first screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same door, but you (or someone else...) changed the position in the instance in the scene. So, go ahead, you can delete it in the prefab and it will be deleted in the instance too :)